# Django admin tabular inline sorting

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to implement the same way of sorting in tabular inline, like in list view. I have found and tried a couple of plugins(There is a `django-admin-sortable2` enabled on the first screenshot), but none of them actually allow to click on the table head and sort by columns(See where my cursor is on screenshot). Is this even possible?

[Here how it is in tabular inline view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC9IP.png)

[Here hot it is in list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztXSk.png)